# React Native Maps - Marker redraw function is still active?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

This is a general question about react native maps I hope someone can solve.

I see this function called redraw in the docs, that should help me redraw the selected marker, but using my ref, I don't see this function (but I see the others).

[image: methods for the react native maps markers]

Does anyone know if they removed it? I can't find information anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your specific use-case, but we use `showCallout` to achieve the same thing.

Each time we receive new location data we call `showCallout` to draw the callout. This effectively redraws the callout.

Comment: I want to redraw the entire marker to change its color. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Oh I see. Not sure then, I will experiment and post anything I find here.